# OraclePreparedStatement Method setStringForClob in java

Tags: java, oracle

I tried to insert CLOB in Oracle DB using below code.

[I found the below code from this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/508848/Oracle-OAS/Insert-CLOB-JDBC)

but setStringForClob is not available , Please let me know What am doing as Wrong.
am using oracle driver ojdbc14.jar and jdk 1.5

```
String sql = "insert into table values('abc',123,?)"; 
OraclePreparedStatement st = (OraclePreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);  
st.setStringForClob(1, /*String variable which contains the CLOB string*/);
```

Comment: Do you actually get a compile error on that line of code?

Comment: ofcourse code not compiled but in that link they updated as it works , so if am using any wrong jar or class please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting a newer JDBC driver ojdbc14.jar is really old.  Use ojdbc6.jar from oracle.

Comment: but this won't work with jdk 1.5 because it expects jdk 1.6.Am I right? Please clarify this.

Comment: THen use ojdbc5.jar  That is compatible with 1.5.